# How to store the Oracle sql query result in multi dimension array in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I've a PHP script to fetch the data from Oracle SQL. I need to include fetch statement in HTML code. Basically I want to process all PHP related and database related queries in PHP tag  and wherever required, i can fetch the result from the array rather again include oci_fetch() and oci_result statements.

e..g,

```
<?php
/* Database Connection*/

if(!$dbConn = oci_connect('WHSUSR','goldeneyex','MyServer.biz:1530/OSLTP')){
    $err = oci_error();
    trigger_error('Could not establish a connection: ' . $err['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
};

/* Query to get Users last accessed appication */
$strSQLUserLogInDetails = "select v.user_name,  max(start_time) from sessiont s inner join V_BO_USER_CODES v on v.user_obj_id = s.user_id
                                    where v.user_name not in ('KALIDO MDM Anonymous User', 'KALIDO MDM Publication Service User')
                            group by v.user_name
                            order by 2 desc";

$stmtUserLogInDetails = oci_parse($dbConn,$strSQLUserLogInDetails);
if ( ! oci_execute($stmtUserLogInDetails) ){
    $err = oci_error($stmtUserLogInDetails);
    trigger_error('Query failed: ' . $err['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
};
?>
```

and HTML code below...

```
<table class="table table-striped" title="List of Users who last accessed Kalido application">
    <thead><tr><th>User Name</th><th>Last Accessed On</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>                     
        <?php
            while(oci_fetch($stmtUserLogInDetails)){
                $uname = oci_result($stmtUserLogInDetails, 1);
                $datetime = oci_result($stmtUserLogInDetails, 2);
                print "<tr><td><a href='userlevelreport.php?uname=".$uname."'>" .$uname. "</a></td><td>".$datetime."</td></tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Just so you know, to format text as Code you just need to select the text and press the `{}` button

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [oci-fetch-array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php).

On that link you have some examples how to use it.

In your particular case:

...

```
$rows = array();
if ( ! oci_execute($stmtUserLogInDetails) ){
    $err = oci_error($stmtUserLogInDetails);
    trigger_error('Query failed: ' . $err['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}
else
{
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $row; 
    }
}
```

$rows will contain an array with your results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)
```